# Compile gloox for Android

Tags: android, compilation, xmpp

I'm trying to develop a XMPP aplicaction for Android using gloox stack, but my problem is that I'm not able to compile this library for Android environment.

Any suggestion for compile gloox for Android?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a xmpp library written in java? It would make your life much easier, since it would be device independent and you didn't have to compile native code.

You can find some xmpp libraries at http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/
And I'm sure there are much more out there.

Comment: Hello henrik, I need use gloox because I have the XMPP client developed for mac, iphone, windows and linux, and running in all of them, using gloox library, so for me, it's much easier only compile the library and not develop a entire client for Android.